# Give DBAdmin access on multiple DB's

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-database

I am trying to provide DBAdmin privilege for a user on multiple databases.
I know how to do from on premises SQL database, I can directly map the user to required databases.

Can anyone let me know how to do it in Azure managed instance. Since the added user is external user, can,t see it in the Logins to map the user.

I have like 100 databases on which the user should have db admin right. Is there a easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Azure Active Directory Login
eg

```
CREATE LOGIN [someuser@somecompany.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

then create users mapped to this login in the appropriate databases, or make this login a sysadmin.  Not sure if this shows up in SSMS, as it was added relatively recently.  So you may have to create the users and grant them permissions in the target databases in TSQL, as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-aad-security-tutorial